# "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException in java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, awt-eventqueue

I'm coding a program for a pizza restaurant and the code must calculate the total price
according to what the customer wants on his pizza.

**Code**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.*;


class Piz 
{
    Double [] small1 ; 
    Double [] medium1 ; 
    Double [] larg1 ; 
    Double [] tomato1 ;
    Double [] olive1 ; 
    Double [] chicken1 ; 
    Double [] meat1 ; 
    Double [] hotdog1 ; 
    Double [] mashrom1; 
    Double [] onion1 ; 


    public Piz ()
    {
      small1 = new Double [2];
      medium1 = new Double [2];
      larg1= new Double [2];

      tomato1= new Double [3];
      olive1 = new Double [3];
      chicken1 = new Double [3];
      meat1 = new Double [3];
      hotdog1 = new Double [3];
      mashrom1 = new Double [3];
      onion1 = new Double [3];  

      small1[0] = 1.5 ; 
      small1[1] = 1.4 ; 

      medium1[0] = 2.5 ; 
      medium1[1] = 2.4 ; 

      larg1[0] = 3.5 ; 
      larg1[1] = 3.4 ;

      tomato1[0] = 0.2 ; 
      tomato1[1] = 0.3 ;
      tomato1[2] = 0.4 ;

      olive1[0] = 0.2 ; 
      olive1[1] = 0.3 ;
      olive1[2] = 0.4 ;

      chicken1[0] = 0.3 ; 
      chicken1[1] = 0.4 ;
      chicken1[2] = 0.5 ;


      hotdog1[0] = 0.3 ; 
      hotdog1[1] = 0.4 ;
      hotdog1[2] = 0.5 ;


      meat1[0] = 0.3 ; 
      meat1[1] = 0.4 ;
      meat1[2] = 0.5 ;


      mashrom1[0] = 0.2 ; 
      mashrom1[1] = 0.3 ;
      mashrom1[2] = 0.4 ;


      onion1[0] = 0.2 ; 
      onion1[1] = 0.3 ;
      onion1[2] = 0.4 ;

    }
}



class PatientFrame extends JFrame
{

    private Piz p;
    private ButtonGroup radioGroup1;
    private ButtonGroup radioGroup2; 
    private JLabel size ; 
    private JLabel topping ;
    private JLabel crust ;
    private JLabel pizzrio; 


    private JButton add ; 
    private JButton cancel;
    private JButton print;


    private JRadioButton small ;
    private JRadioButton medium ;
    private JRadioButton larg ;

    private JRadioButton thick;
    private JRadioButton thin;


    private JCheckBox tomato ; 
    private JCheckBox olives ;
    private JCheckBox chicken ; 
    private JCheckBox meat ;
    private JCheckBox hotdog ;
    private JCheckBox mashroom ; 
    private JCheckBox onion ;


    private JTextArea text1 ; 


    private ImageIcon icon ;


    public PatientFrame()
    {
        super ("p i Z z R i O");

        add = new JButton ("Add");

        setLayout (new FlowLayout());

        size = new JLabel ("Size");
        topping = new JLabel ("Topping");
        crust = new JLabel ("Crust");

        small = new JRadioButton ("Small" ,true);
        medium = new JRadioButton ("Medium", false);
        larg = new JRadioButton ("Larg" , false);

        radioGroup1 = new ButtonGroup();
        radioGroup1.add (small);
        radioGroup1.add (medium);
        radioGroup1.add (larg);

        thick = new JRadioButton ("Thick" ,true);
        thin = new JRadioButton ("Thin" ,false);

        radioGroup2 = new ButtonGroup();
        radioGroup2.add (thick);
        radioGroup2.add (thin);

        tomato = new JCheckBox ("Tomato");
        olives = new JCheckBox ("Olives");
        chicken = new JCheckBox ("Chicken");
        meat = new JCheckBox ("Meat");
        hotdog = new JCheckBox ("Totdog");
        mashroom = new JCheckBox ("Mashroom");
        onion = new JCheckBox ("Onion");

        Box box = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        text1 = new JTextArea( 40 , 40);
        box.add ( new JScrollPane(text1));



        pizzrio = new JLabel ("p i Z z R i O");
        pizzrio.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        add (pizzrio);
        add ( topping );
        add ( crust );

        add(small);
        add(medium);
        add(larg);

        add(tomato);
        add(olives);
        add(chicken);
        add(meat);
        add(hotdog);
        add(mashroom);
        add (onion);

        add(thick);
        add(thin);

        add(add);
        add(box);

        text1.setText("      Size       Topping                                                                Crust            Price");

        EventHandler han = new EventHandler() ;
        add.addActionListener(han);



    }


    private class EventHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            String [] toppinglist = new String [20] ;
            String s = "";
            String c = "";
            Double sizep = 0.0 ;
            Double toppingp = 0.0 ;
            int count = 0 ;  

            if (small.isSelected() && thick.isSelected())
            {  
                sizep = p.small1[0];
                s = small.getText() ;
                c= "Thick";

                if (tomato.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.tomato1[0];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Tomato";
                    count ++ ; 
                }

                if (olives.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.olive1[0];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Olives";
                    count ++ ;
                }

                if (chicken.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.chicken1[0];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Chicken";
                    count ++ ;
                }


                if (meat.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.meat1[0];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Meat";
                    count ++ ;
                }


                if (hotdog.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.hotdog1[0];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Hotdog";
                    count ++ ;
                }


                if (mashroom.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.mashrom1[0];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Mashroom";
                    count ++ ;
                }


                if (onion.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.onion1[0];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Onion";
                    count ++ ;
                }


            }



            if (small.isSelected() && thin.isSelected())
            {
                sizep = p.small1[1];
                s = "Small" ; 
                c = "Thin";

                if (tomato.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.tomato1[0];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Tomato";
                    count ++ ; 
                }

                if (olives.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.olive1[0];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Olives";
                    count ++ ;
                }

                if (chicken.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.chicken1[0];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Chicken";
                    count ++ ;
                }


                if (meat.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.meat1[0];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Meat";
                    count ++ ;
                }


                if (hotdog.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.hotdog1[0];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Hotdog";
                    count ++ ;
                }


                if (mashroom.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.mashrom1[0];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Mashroom";
                    count ++ ;
                }


                if (onion.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.onion1[0];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Onion";
                    count ++ ;
                }

            } 




            if (medium.isSelected() && thick.isSelected())
            {
                sizep = p.medium1[0];
                s = "Medium";
                c = "Thick" ; 


                if (tomato.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.tomato1[1];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Tomato";
                    count ++ ; 
                }

                if (olives.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.olive1[1];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Olives";
                    count ++ ;
                }

                if (chicken.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.chicken1[1];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Chicken";
                    count ++ ;
                }


                if (meat.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.meat1[1];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Meat";
                    count ++ ;
                }


                if (hotdog.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.hotdog1[1];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Hotdog";
                    count ++ ;
                }


                if (mashroom.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.mashrom1[1];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Mashroom";
                    count ++ ;
                }


                if (onion.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.onion1[1];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Onion";
                    count ++ ;
                }
            }



            if (medium.isSelected() && thin.isSelected())
            {
                sizep = p.medium1[1];
                s = "Medium";
                c = "Thin" ;


                if (tomato.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.tomato1[1];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Tomato";
                    count ++ ; 
                }

                if (olives.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.olive1[1];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Olives";
                    count ++ ;
                }

                if (chicken.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.chicken1[1];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Chicken";
                    count ++ ;
                }


                if (meat.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.meat1[1];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Meat";
                    count ++ ;
                }


                if (hotdog.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.hotdog1[1];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Hotdog";
                    count ++ ;
                }


                if (mashroom.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.mashrom1[1];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Mashroom";
                    count ++ ;
                }


                if (onion.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.onion1[1];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Onion";
                    count ++ ;
                }

            }

            if (larg.isSelected() && thick.isSelected())
            {
                sizep = p.larg1[0];
                s = "Larg";
                c = "Thick" ;

                if (tomato.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.tomato1[2];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Tomato";
                    count ++ ; 
                }

                if (olives.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.olive1[2];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Olives";
                    count ++ ;
                }

                if (chicken.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.chicken1[2];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Chicken";
                    count ++ ;
                }


                if (meat.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.meat1[2];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Meat";
                    count ++ ;
                }


                if (hotdog.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.hotdog1[2];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Hotdog";
                    count ++ ;
                }


                if (mashroom.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.mashrom1[2];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Mashroom";
                    count ++ ;
                }


                if (onion.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.onion1[2];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Onion";
                    count ++ ;
                }
            }

            if (larg.isSelected() && thin.isSelected())
            {

                sizep = p.larg1[1];
                s = "Larg";
                c = "Thin" ;


                if (tomato.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.tomato1[2];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Tomato";
                    count ++ ; 
                }

                if (olives.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.olive1[2];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Olives";
                    count ++ ;
                }

                if (chicken.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.chicken1[2];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Chicken";
                    count ++ ;
                }


                if (meat.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.meat1[2];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Meat";
                    count ++ ;
                }


                if (hotdog.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.hotdog1[2];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Hotdog";
                    count ++ ;
                }


                if (mashroom.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.mashrom1[2];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Mashroom";
                    count ++ ;
                }


                if (onion.isSelected())
                {
                    toppingp = toppingp + p.onion1[2];
                    toppinglist[count] = "Onion";
                    count ++ ;
                }
            }

            String sizepp = String.valueOf(sizep);
            if (event.getSource() == add)
                text1.setText(sizepp);
        }
    }


}

public class Ass03 
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        PatientFrame patientFrame1 = new PatientFrame();
        patientFrame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        patientFrame1.setSize(700,304);
        patientFrame1.setVisible(true);


    }
}
```

**Stack trace**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at PatientFrame$EventHandler.actionPerformed(Ass03.java:213)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

I hope you can help me to find out where the error came from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important line of your stack trace is this one:

```
at PatientFrame$EventHandler.actionPerformed(Ass03.java:213)
```

Basically, it tells you that you have a `NULL` object at line 213.
Assuming you have pasted your whole code, it corresponds to this line:

```
sizep = p.small1[0];
```

You are trying to get `small1` attribute of `p`, which is unassigned. And I can't find any assignment to `p` variable. Maybe you've missed it in the constructor?